# Another Makefile question

Tags: makefile, assembly

I have a simple application consisting of a small number of files. The files are
apptest.c, apptest.h, apptest.S. What is confusing me a bit is the part where the
apptest_AUTO.s comes into play. Anyone have an idea what is the purpose of doing that?
I could imagine that another copy of the assembler code is being made after it is 
being processed by the pre-processor before it is actually used as input to the Assembly?

```
CC=/bin/sparc-elf-gcc
CPP=/bin/sparc-elf-cpp
CIS_ASM=bin/sparc-elf-as

all: apptest.exe

apptest.exe: apptest.o
 $(CC) apptest.o -o apptest.exe

apptest.o: apptest.c apptest.h apptest.S
 $(CC) $(SFLAGS) apptest.c -o apptest_AUTO.s
 $(CPP) apptest.S >> apptest_AUTO.s
 $(CIS_ASM) apptest_AUTO.s -o apptest.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone wanted the opportunity to automatically modify the assembler source before compiling it to object code.  I've seen it done before, not for SPARC but typically much older architectures (M680x0, Z8000) and much older C compilers (1980s, not 2010s).

Given the sequence shown, it seems unlikely to be doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a odd way of doing things, but it is pasting a preprocessed version of apptest.S onto the end of the assembler code output by compiling apptest.c.  The end result would be a single object file which is built from both apptest.c and apptest.S.

Looks like a hack to prevent name clash between the two object files.  A more conventional approach would be something like,

```
CC=/bin/sparc-elf-gcc
CPP=/bin/sparc-elf-cpp
CIS_ASM=bin/sparc-elf-as

all: apptest.exe

apptest.exe: apptest.o apptest.s.o
    $(CC) $+ -o apptest.exe

apptest.o: apptest.c apptest.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) apptest.c -o apptest.o

apptest.s.o: apptest.s
    $(CIS_ASM) apptest.s -o apptest.s.o
```